# How to make a variable accessible from a different swift file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to be able to use a variable in one file in another.

For example I created an array of core data items in one view controller, but I want to use it in another view controller.

Comment: The link helps you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 2):

Core Data is to manage the model layer objects in your application. Why did you create an array of core data items in one view controller?

According to [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1), you should do do initializing the Core Data Stack.

just like

```
class MyDataController: NSObject {
    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer!

    //  ...

}
```

And you can fetch it in almost every file. just like :

```
let moc = …
let employeesFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")

do {
    let fetchedEmployees = try moc.executeFetchRequest(employeesFetch) as! [EmployeeMO]
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: I have a class with three variables saved to core data. I made an array to be able to display just the titles of all the items and display them to a tableview controller.
Aside from the fact they're core data. How would a variable typically be pulled from one VC to another?

Comment: I learned from a tutorial I purchased on stack skills, but I think you've made me realize I should've learned from the documentation because I don't quite understand the details

Comment: If you just want to pass data from one ViewController to another, why do you need CoreData? CoreData make you data persistent to Cache/Disk. Then you can fetch the data from anywhere. Like like UserDefaults save and fetch little data.

Answer (score 1):

You could create one property in ViewControllerB like this,

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    var dataItems: [DataItem] = []
}
```

so when you navigate from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB you could set the data to the property like below,

```
let viewControllerB = ViewControllerB()
viewControllerB.dataItems = [...]
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)
```

Hope this helps!